# Que veut dire « déroutant » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

J’ai rencontré ce mot dans un jeu vidéo anglais, qui était partout pourvu de sous-titres français. Quelqu’un a parcouru le jeu, et avait tout enregistré avec tel ou tel logiciel. Ainsi, il a mis en ligne ce jeu. Le mot apparaissait dans les phrases suivantes :

> Quel personnage déroutant ! J’aurais aimé le rencontrer de son vivant.
>
> What a perplexing individual ! I wish I could have met him while he
>   was still alive.

J’ai choisi d’inclure l’anglais pour la complétude. J’espère que j’ai tout bien écrit.

Sans utiliser un dictionnaire, je dirais que *déroutant* veuille dire *épatant*. 
Étrangement, le Wiktionnaire dit que *déroutant* désigne *qui déroute*, et que *dérouter* c’est un peu comme *empêcher quelque chose d’aboutir* ou *déranger*.  Cet ensemble d’explications renforce les mauvais desseins d’un « personnage déroutant ». Le Trésor définit ce mot de façon pareille. Ça ne s’accompagne pas avec le récit ou ce mot décrit un homme insolite mais bienveillant.

Maintenant, je cherche surtout une réponse pour cette question : À propos de « déroutant », Quand est-ce qu’il souligne que quelqu’un a des mauvaises fins, et quand témoigne-t-il du bon cœur de la personne décrite ?

Comment: La définition B.2 du TLFi: _Mettre dans l'embarras, déconcerter._ me semble être celle adéquate dans le contexte.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Déroutant est neutre. Il n'a pas de connotation positive ou négative.

Cet adjectif signifie ici simplement le caractère inattendu et déconcertant du personnage.

Comment: @koenraad-van-duin  Avec les mêmes définitions (inattendu, déconcertant) le Robert donne pour exemples : "Une question déroutante (inattendue) ; son attitude est déroutante, il est déroutant." - Il n'y a pas la notion négative que l'on peut trouver dans *dérouter*, seulement quelque chose ou quelqu'un qui ne se comporte pas du tout comme on pouvait s'y attendre.